# SQL that creates a new table, essentially, but with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

```
def reports
  sql = "select username, email, sign_in_count, current_sign_in_at, \
          (select count(*) from foo ft where ft.user_id = u.id and ft.state in ('complete', 'active', 'win', 'lose')) as foo_state, \
          (select count(*) from bar where creator_id = u.id and m.state not in ('new','cancelled')) as bar_created, \
        from users u where sign_in_count > 0 order by foo_state desc;"
  @users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

So, this query is botched a bit for purposes of showing you something, but not bothering you with the details. This query takes a few different tables, queries them, and returns a new table essentially. I'm using postgreSQL, so this returns a `PG::Result` object. I can call `@users.values` to get an array of arrays, but I was wondering if there was a more 'rails-y' way do do this?

I'd like to do something like this in the view:

```
<%= render partial: 'users/shared/user', collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

but since it's not an actual ActiveRecord object, I can't seem to do that (although it doesn't throw an error if I try, it just doesn't display anything)

Can ARel accomplish a feat like this? Am I asking too much? Thanks!

For anyone else stumbling upon this... this works to get your info, at least:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% @users.fields.each do |f| %>
        <th><%= f %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.values.each do |v| %>
      <tr>
        <% v.each do |a| %>
          <td><%= a %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```